# how to sum row values together and merge in pandas dataframe python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
Date(UTC)            Type  Amount   
2020-10-09 04:00:37  SELL  2045.0 
2020-10-09 03:04:29  SELL  2045.0 
2020-10-09 02:37:43  SELL  1376.0
2020-10-09 02:37:24  SELL   669.0
2020-10-09 01:35:17  SELL  2045.0
```

From above you can see that row 3 and 4 have 'Amount': 1376.0 + 669.0 = 2045.0. What is the simplest way of merging all rows with 'Amount" values sequentially equal to 2045 into a single row like this:

```
Date(UTC)            Type  Amount   
2020-10-09 04:00:37  SELL  2045.0 
2020-10-09 03:04:29  SELL  2045.0 
2020-10-09 02:37:43  SELL  2045.0
2020-10-09 01:35:17  SELL  2045.0
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you are looking for. Do you want to consolidate all consecutive BUY/SELL lines into one, so that you end up with alternating BUY/SELL lines? Maybe a bit more data would be helpful as well.

Comment: I just need to sum the rows which are equal to 2045 and merge them. I've edited the post to only show 'SELL' in the 'Type' column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only interested in the sum irrespective of the "Type".

Step 1: d.reset_index(inplace=True)
Now your dataFrame will look like this. (Ignore the "Date(UTC)" column for now)

```
        index Date(UTC)  Type  Amount
0  2020-10-09  04:00:37   BUY  2045.0
1  2020-10-09  03:04:29  SELL  2045.0
2  2020-10-09  02:37:43  SELL  1376.0
3  2020-10-09  02:37:24  SELL   669.0
4  2020-10-09  01:35:17   BUY  2045.0
5  2020-10-09  04:00:37   BUY  2045.0
6  2020-10-09  03:04:29  SELL  2045.0
7  2020-10-09  02:37:43  SELL  1376.0
8  2020-10-09  02:37:24  SELL   669.0
9  2020-10-09  01:35:17   BUY  2045.0
```

Step 2: Get the consecutive indices (remove 2045 ones we don't need them):

```
Input:
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(d[d.Amount != 2045].index), lambda x: x[0]-x[1]):
...     print(list(map(itemgetter(1), g)))

Output:
[2, 3]
[7, 8]
```

Comment: What is step 3? How to merge rows?

Comment: Save the above results in a list. So that you have a list of lists. Then you can iterate through that list and do something like d.loc[ [2,3] , "Amount" ].sum() and save it to the last element or some other dataframe. You'll have to also figure out what happens if there are more than 2 elements, --> say d.loc[ [41,42,43] , "Amount" ].sum() is greater than 2045 then you might have to start removing elements from the end and check the sum again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy, I am sure there is a nicer way.

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.index + " " + df["Date(UTC)"])
df = df.drop("Date(UTC)", axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
# mark all lines where Amount is already 2045
df["x"] = df["Amount"] == 2045
# next we mark lines where either Amount is already 2045 or we are 
# switching between values.
# This will let us create groups within which we should sum 
# values
df["switch"] = df["x"] | (df["x"] != df["x"].shift())
# now we create group markers 
df["group"] = df["switch"].cumsum()
# next we use groupby to sum Amount within each group
# the result we expect is 2045 of course
# then we merge this with the original dataframe and only keep the first line
res = (
    df.merge(
        df.groupby(by="group")["Amount"].sum().reset_index(), on="group", how="left"
    )
    .groupby(by=["group"])
    .first()
    .drop(["Amount_x", "x", "switch"], axis=1)
)
print(res)
```

I am not sure if this is really what you are looking for. E.g. there could be cases where Amount does not add up to 2045. Maybe they add up to 2*2045, should these then be split into 2 rows, etc.?

```
       Type                date  Amount_y
group                                    
1      SELL 2020-10-09 04:00:37    2045.0
2      SELL 2020-10-09 03:04:29    2045.0
3      SELL 2020-10-09 02:37:43    2045.0
4      SELL 2020-10-09 01:35:17    2045.0
```